# PDF reader for the CLI

Tags: linux, vim, pdf, shell, pdf-reader

I'm looking for a PDF reader that I can use over SSH in a terminal, and have it running in `screen`. Does such a thing exist?

Ideally I'd like at least a `less`-esque pager but with some PDF formatting, page numbering, and maybe even navigation through links in the document. Vim integration would be awesome but I'm afraid I'm asking for too much with that. I'd love if you proved me wrong, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of anything better than using [`pdftotext`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext), but that and `less` work in a pinch. There are other converters, too. Maybe `pdftohtml` and `lynx`/`links`/`elinks`/`links2`/`w3m`  (textmode browsers) could "render" some stuff better.

Answer (score 2):

All I can find is a number of rather hackish solutions that involve installing a tool called `pdftohtml` or `pdftotext` and then viewing the resultant files.

So make sure whatever flavour of linux you are using has pdftohtml then

```
pdftohtml ch.01.pdf
```

Followed by

```
lynx ch.o1.html
```

(Found at http://bassemreda.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/console-pdf-viewer/)

Googling for `console pdf viewer` only returns pages that state that there is no console pdf viewer and the best you can do is either convert it to html (as above) to keep the formatting or extract the text from it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a project called [fbida](http://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/):

> The fbida project contains a few
> applications for viewing and editing
> images, with the main focus being
> photos. The applications are:
>
> fbi – This is a image viewer for the
> linux framebuffer console.
>
> fbgs – **A
> wrapper script for viewing ps/pdf
> files on the framebuffer console using
> fbi**.
>
> [...]

Comment: Looks nice, but I can't think of a way to use framebuffer over SSH.. At least not any easier than it would be to set up full-blown X forwarding.